# how to install clang 3.4 build tool in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, clang

I am running the C++ cross platform sample "MoreTeaPotsAndroid" provided in Visual Studio 2015. The problem is the sample was built by clang tool 3.4 but Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 came with clang tool 3.6. I tried to upgrade the project and use clang tool 3.6 to build it but it seem like not compatible. Anyone can help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that it would not work. Microsoft has provided patches to the latest versions of clang to make it work in Visual Studio. Older releases would therefore likely have problems.

Comment: Oic. Do you use visual studio to do cross platform c++ android app before?